# How to check if first and last numbers in a list are the same?

Tags: python

> Given a list of numbers, return `True` if the first and last numbers
> of a list are the same.
>
> Expected Output: Given list is `[10, 20, 30, 40, 10]` the result is
> `True`. Given list is `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]` result is `False`

Below is my code:

```
list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 10]
for num in list:
    if num[0] == num[-1]:
        print('Result is True')
    else:
        print('Result is False')
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Why do you need to iterate through the list. It would work fine without that

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name since `list` already has a built-in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

When you use
`for num in list:` you iterate over the integers in the list, in other words, num is an integer and not a list so it is not iterable, you can simply check by doing this without iterating over the list :

```
nums = [10, 20, 30, 40, 10]
if nums[0] == nums[-1]:
    print('Result is True')
else:
    print('Result is False')
```

Comment: Thanks all. So by doing for num in the list, it means iterate over every entry in the list. And num itself is an integer in this scenario. Hence it is not iterable i.e. subscriptable. Makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the for loop, just ask for [0] and [-1] this are already the elemets of the array

```
list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 10]
if list[0] == list[-1]:
    print('Result is True')
else:
    print('Result is False')
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, you don't need a `for` loop to just find compare first and last item of a list.

```py
my_list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 10]

if my_list[0] == my_list[-1]:
    print('Result is True')
else:
    print('Result is False')
```

Also `list()` is a constructor and `list` is a data type in Python, skip using it as a variable name. Same goes for dict, set etc, please read more Official Documentation of [Python Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one!

```
collections = [10, 20, 30, 40, 10]
print("Yes") if collections[0] == collections[-1] else print("No")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a for loop as you are only comparing two values of which both can be accessed as such: `list[0]` and `list[-1]`.

So your full code would only be:

```py
if list[0] == list[-1]:
    #true
else:
    #false
```